# How to log all incompaitable rows in storage account using ADF V2 copy data tools

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have selected the option of logging all the incompatible rows into the storage account default container, but there have been no logs written inside the storage account, I am wondering why is that not happening?
Is there anything which can be done to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It's a regression and we are working on the fix, it's expected to be deployed by end of this week. Please try after that.

Update:
The issue is fixed, can you try again?

Comment: I am using polybase with the pipelines. Is this supported for logging incompatible rows?

Comment: It's not supported for now and it's on our roadmap.